# How to cope with new/unseen targets classes in incremental learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification

According to [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html), the sklearn incremental learner itself may be unable to cope with new/unseen targets classes. Is there any available python machine learning library which support this functionality?

Comment: What is the context? What exactly is your aim? Generally, you only can predict what the model has learned before...

Comment: Here I am going to classify ransomware into ransomware families. In this context new families pop up frequently. So rather than train whole model again,here I hope to modify model with new family

Comment: Right, I see the problem. However, with supervised learning the model can only identify what it has learned before. You could look into unsupervised methods (I'm not an expert in this field). At least this is what I can think about. The idea would be to "cluster" types of outcomes.

Comment: Yeah thanks. The Lazy Learning technique will more appropriate in my case

Answer (score 1):

[Scikit-multiflow](https://scikit-multiflow.github.io/) is a package designed for incremental learning for multi-output/multi-label problems.